# TLS connection through proxy

Tags: node.js, ssl, proxy, certificate

We want to establish a TLS encrypted connection between a node.js client behind our company proxy and a node.js server in the internet (which we control, too).

I am confused by this issue, how can we keep our certificate based security approach with TLS through a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TLS proxy is transparent. The client sends a CONNECT request, which has the target host name and port, then the proxy creates a new TCP connection to that host, and after that does nothing else than move packets between the client and the server connection.

So from the client's point of view, the certificate the client retreives from the proxy will be exactly the bytes the server sent.

On the server side, the IP you'll be seeing is that of the proxy, not that of the client. So you shouldn't use a *server* certificate in the client, as the CN from the certificate and the IP / reverse looked up host name won't match. But if you use a client certificate, the proxy will again pass it to the server without modifying anyting - so if you do some "was this client certificate signed by a CA i trust" checking on the server, everything will work fine.